# Haskell: ghc package environment

Tags: haskell

Hi in my package `toaster`, i `cabal v2-install lib:toaster --package-env ~/myenv/`

In the `~/myenv/` dir, there is `.ghc.environment.x86_64-linux-9.2.2`

I've also set the environment variable to point to the `myenv` dir.

Unfortunately, `cabal install` doesn't update the environment.

Am i doing the wrong way?

when I `runghc Hello.hs`, it says that `toaster` is hidden.

**Found the answer:**

`cabal install --lib lib:toaster --overwrite-policy=always --env ~/dev/haskell/pkg_env/`

Comment: Why do you do it this way at all? It looks like `Hello.hs` should be an executable of your package, and you should execute it with `cabal run` instead of `runghc`. Then there's no need to bother with any manual library-installation trouble. But you should provide more information so we can assess it for sure.

Comment: @leftaroundabout i develop my own lib `toaster` and i would like to runghc somescript.hs ,using my `toaster` lib

Comment: But why? Why don't you just run that script with Cabal (and/or install it as an executable that could then be run from anywhere without GHC or Cabal)?

Comment: @leftaroundabout let me put it another way: how can you install a non-hackage package into the package environment?   with hackage, i can `cabal install --lib somelib --env .`

Comment: You don't, you instead add a `cabal.project` file pointing to the package you want to “install”. Then, as usual, you never explicitly install the package at all but instead just let Cabal handle the dependency on it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ok i finally understand what you mean. I've checked out the cabal.project file...   anyway, my original use case is to use haskell as a scripting language, calling it anywhere while editing in an emacs buffer, processing some text in that buffer.

Comment: Haskell `stack` tool supports this: https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/stack-script/

Answer (score 1):

By default, `cabal install` only installs executables, storing libraries built along the way only in its cache. If you want the library to be put somewhere, you must add `--lib` to your `cabal install` line.

Comment: Thanks. How do you install your non-hackage library with `cabal install --lib ` so that you can make use of the library in a script, such as runghc myscript.hs?

Comment: @McBearHolden ...the exact same way? I don't really see what Hackage has to do with it. Jump into the directory with the library and type `cabal install --lib`. But mostly I wouldn't. Instead I'd just make a package with executables that depends on the library, and install those (as the scripts). (In other words: in this answer and comment I am trying to help you do the thing you asked to do, but I think you asked for the wrong thing.)

Comment: Yes, creating a local package is the right way to go. In that case you can leverage cabal.project file to get packages from outside of Hackage.